# How to get current Cursor or Mouse in tinymce

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce

I am working Text Editor in Tinymce in Vuejs. I need to insert string by its position. But I cannot get exact position. I tried `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getRng()` gave a wrong position when I break lines. Does anyone know how to get any position?

Answer (score 0):

```js
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<span class="lngtbllbl">Table 1:</span>');
```

Comment: In tinymce, there is command to insert content. It will insert content automatically. where is your cursor.